# Android studio gradle error after upgrade to 1.4 - error: Cause:https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgraded to Windows 10 and to latest version of studio (1.4). I'm trying to import a project I have been working on (it was working ok before).

I'm running into a critical error:

> "Gradle 'Reiki' project refresh failed:
>   Error: Cause:https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip"

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have spent a couple of hours looking at other studio gradle questions and answers and can't find this particular issue:.

The error code is below:

> 2015-10-03 20:27:34,111 [  36960]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -
>   2015-10-03 20:27:34,112 [  36961]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - >Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
>   2015-10-03 20:27:34,112 [  36961]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - >Sync with Gradle for project 'Reiki' failed: Cause: >https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
>   2015-10-03 20:27:34,300 [  37149]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - >Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2015-10-03 20:27:34,300 [  37149]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - >Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2015-10-03 20:27:34,300 [  37149]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - >Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2015-10-03 20:27:34,300 [  37149]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - >Saving symbols finished in 0 s.

Comment: Currently the gradle-wrapper.properties file has the following:  
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link

```
https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip
```

is **wrong**.

Check the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and use:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Hi Gabrielle - the gradle-wrapper.properties already has that link:#Sun Jan 18 17:44:30 EST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1_all.zip

Comment: @OmahaNebrasca Read better the answer. 2.2.1_all is not 2.2.1-all

Comment: Thankyou for this, small change got me past this gradle error. I'm now running into a different error ('failed to find target -android-20') but I'll check if there is a separate thread on that problem. Thanks for your help.